# Python pandas, how to transform a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

if I have a dataframe:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'grp':['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 'pos' : [1, 2, 1, 2, 3], 'desc1' : ['X1', 'X2', 'Y1', 'Y2', 'Y3'], 'desc2' : ['A1', 'A2', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3']})
>>> df['desc'] = df.desc1 + ' (' + df.desc2 + ')'
>>> df = df.drop(columns=['desc1', 'desc2'])
>>> df
  grp  pos     desc
0   A    1  X1 (A1)
1   A    2  X2 (A2)
2   B    1  Y1 (A1)
3   B    2  Y2 (A2)
4   B    3  Y3 (A3)
>>>
```

I would like to transform i to the following dataframe:

```
  grp     pos1     pos2     pos3
0   A  X1 (A1)  X2 (A2)     None
1   B  Y1 (A1)  Y2 (A2)  Y3 (A3)
```

I would like to group everything by "grp" and for each position to have desc in column cell.
Groups have variable number of positions.
How to do the transformation?

Regards.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530568/can-pandas-groupby-aggregate-into-a-list-rather-than-sum-mean-etc

Answer (score 2):

IIUC `pd.crosstab`

```
df1 = pd.crosstab(df.grp,df.pos,df.desc,aggfunc=lambda x : x)\
                .add_prefix('pos')\
                .reset_index()\
                .rename_axis(None,axis=1)

print(df1)
  grp     pos1     pos2     pos3
0   A  X1 (A1)  X2 (A2)      NaN
1   B  Y1 (A1)  Y2 (A2)  Y3 (A3)
```

Comment: It works. Interesting usage of lambda function. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could solve it using groupby and unstack:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'grp':['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 'pos' : [1, 2, 1, 2, 3], 'desc1' : ['X1', 'X2', 'Y1', 'Y2', 'Y3'], 'desc2' : ['A1', 'A2', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3']})
df['desc'] = df.desc1 + ' (' + df.desc2 + ')'
df = df.drop(columns=['desc1', 'desc2'])

df1 = df.groupby(['grp', 'pos'])['desc'].first().unstack('pos')
print(df1)
#Output:
pos        1        2        3
grp                           
A    X1 (A1)  X2 (A2)      NaN
B    Y1 (A1)  Y2 (A2)  Y3 (A3)
```